# Reinforcement learning with multiple variables and products

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I have been reading a lot about Reinforcement Learning (RL) lately, All the material covers about applying RL to one Item (Predicting price of a single stock, price of a single flight) using one variable (historical stock price, historical flight price).

My usecase is that, lets say I have 1000s of products selling on my website. I have details about all the transactions of these items sold.
For every item, I would like to find the optimal price point by looking at the historical information (quantity sold, price, category).

Is it possible to apply RL to multiple products with each product having multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

While this is technically possible with Reinforcement Learning, you're going to find it to be both impossible and impractical without an infinite amount of computation and time. This is mainly due to how policies and/or networks are trained with Reinforcement Learning.

Reinforcement Learning involves an ***agent***, which makes ***observations*** and takes ***actions*** within an ***environment***, and through those actions it will receive a ***reward***. The agent will then attempt to learn and act in a way that will ***maximize*** the expected rewards over time. The reason all of the material you have seen applies RL to one item is because there is only **one reward value** assigned for each set of actions the policy/network takes, and thus there is no way for the agent to receive specific ***credit*** for which of the actions it took were good or bad.

The main issue lies in the reward function. Let's assume a simple case where you are training an agent to find the optimal price point for **two products** at each timestep. If you give the agent a positive reward for taking a ***"good"*** action (choosing a good price point) for one product, but the agent chooses a ***"bad"*** price point for the other, you end up giving the agent a reward that is skewed by the conflicting results, meaning the agent can't actually determine that the first action it took was *"good"* and the second action was *"bad"*. In the simplest case, if you gave the agent +1 reward for the first action, and -1 reward for the second one, the resulting reward would just be **0** and the agent would learn **nothing**.

On a smaller scale, such as the case with only two products, the agent could eventually learn the dynamics between the two and optimize its actions to maximize the expected rewards over time. But this issue only gets worse as you add more products, as more and more components adjust the reward function at each timestep and therefore the agent gets less and less information about how good each of its individual actions actually were.

I believe what you are looking for would be something closer to GRUs or LSTMs, which can use historical data similarly to how you described, but would be able to give a model a more complete picture of how accurate each of its predictions are.

Hopefully, that helps!